cabal update never completes
On my CentOS 7 I have installed cabal-install thus:
yum install cabal-install

This was successful.
When I try to use it to install something it reports (not unexpectedly):-
You may need to run 'cabal update' to get the latest list of available packages.

So I try to do this.
cabal update

This takes hours, but does finally complete. At the end it reports:-
Note: there is a new version of cabal-install available.
To upgrade, run: cabal install cabal-install

So I try to do exactly that, to which it reports:-
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: internal error when reading packing index: failed to parse .cabal
fileThe package index or index cache is probably corrupt. Running cabal update
might fix it.

Surely cabal update is what literally just created it?
Anyway, I tried it again, left it for hours to finish, it said:-
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org

and then everything was just the same as before. It hadn't fixed anything.
What does one do to diagnose and fix this? All I want is to install shelltestrunner!

Wow, hours is too long. cabal update should only take 10-15 seconds. To me it sounds like some network timeout -- can you run it in verbose mode or something and see if anything suspicious comes up? Do you have a firewall? If so, perhaps check its logs and see if it's blocking something that it shouldn't be, maybe? Do you have a networked filesystem that might not be connected exactly right?

I would remove all the Haskell related yum packages and just use GHCup to install and update cabal.

Thanks @Noughtmare - your comment led me to success. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it (and update it with my exact steps).

I would remove all the Haskell related yum packages and just use GHCup to install and update cabal.
GHCup has become the standard way to set up Haskell tooling for development. Packages from Linux distributions tend to not be supported very well for the use case of actual Haskell development.
